# Automatically raising an exception if value is null

Tags: c#

In my class I've done this:

```
private void RaiseExceptionIfNull(object o, string error)
{
    if (o == null) {
        throw new System.NullReferenceException(error + " is null " +
                                                "(should never be null)");
    }
}
```

And then in all my methods, I'm doing stuff like this:

```
RaiseExceptionIfNull(cbAjaxFinished, "Callback Ajax Finished");
RaiseExceptionIfNull(j, "Result conversion");
```

... all of this because I'd like to raise an exception if value is null in one line (with **clean** code).

I was wondering if there's already a way to raise an exception like I do, but in C# (I'm a newbie in this area) (kind of "`assert()` in `C`", but with custom exception).

Comment: Are you looking for [`Debug.Assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63efys0(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: FYI [Assertions in managed code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcc4x86.aspx)

Comment: I guess you are looking for throw expressions in C#7

Comment: It's Unity C# version (not a recent one I guess)

Comment: Another issue with your method is that it pollutes the call stack. Honestly you are better off just writing `if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x))` back in the calling method and using good parameter names. Or in C# 7 use a throw expression.

Comment: Generally in C#, I would recommend using `Debug.Assert` for that purpose except for libraries writers when passing a `null` is clearly a programmer mistake. The .NET framework already detect null access so, in practice, the only reason to be explicit is for a "library" intended to be used by other programmers if there are distinct teams or if the code is intended to used by third-party.

Comment: @Phil1970 It's about handling TCP/IP callbacks (Json tranformation doesnt raise errors, but gives me a "null" object! (or sets some values of the objects as null whereas they are int or strings) so I need to check this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would throw an `ArgumentNullException` instead of using `NullReferenceException` since your are checking for an argument to be invalid because it's `null`. With extension methods, you can achieve a one-liner check very easily:

```
// value types should be excluded as they can't be null
// hence the "where T : class" clause
internal static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T obj, String parameterName) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
}
```

Then, in your methods use the extension as follows:

```
public void MyFunc(Object obj)
{
    obj.ThrowIfNull(nameof(obj));

    // Your implementation...
}
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution, but I can't use "into" my generic class `public class GenericAjaxGetPost<T> {}` and the other problem is that I'd like to be able to use it on a delegate, for example a function that gets a delegate as a parameter and makes a test like `RaiseExceptionIfNull(cbDisplayFatalError, "Callback fatal error");`

Comment: You should use `nameof(obj)` instead of `"obj"`. It makes the code less fragile to refactoring and copy & paste programming (i.e. forgetting to update the string).